# Managing Site Permissions

Tags: permissions, security, meeting-workspace

I am new to SharePoint and having some difficulty setting up the appropriate permissions.

My organization uses a primary landing page that only a few have Owner/Full Control rights to, and then that has separate links to other department pages. Each department page is a meeting workspace. I am attempting to setup permission for someone to have Owner rights on the meeting workspace, but when I do it only allows them to edit what is already in place - not add new document list objects or new pages. Is there something that I am missing here?

I also did some research on how the hierarchy should be setup for SharePoint, going from least secure to most secure. Unfortunately with our setup our levels of security are based upon the departments - would it be best to stop inheritance at each department page?

Answer (score 0):

When you say each department page is a meeting work spaces. According to SharePoint, then its a sub site that is under the primary site or landing page. Make sure you had chosen to inherit permissions from the top site so that the person with full rights on the landing page will have the same rights on the sub sites as well.

For your decision on whether to inherit or breaking permission, it is your take on how granular you want the permission to go. 
If there is a necessity that you want each departments to have unique permissions and only certain groups should have access then you need to break the inheritance and plan accordingly.

Thanks,
Aravind.